# I can not save the valre in the database after creating the field

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

hi I wanted to report a problem I can not save the valre in the database after creating the field.

\ Vendor \ backpack \ newscrud \ src \ app \ Http \ Controllers \ Admin \ ArticleCrudController.php

new field to insert description

```php
$ This-> crud-> addField ([ 'name' => 'description', 'label' => 'Description', 'type' => 'text', 'placeholder' => 'Description meta tag
```

when I go to insert or modify the value in the form admin / article / create I don't modify or save the value in the database
how can I do?

Answer (score 1):

\vendor\backpack\newscrud\src\app\Models\Article.php
My guess is that you didn't add the field to the $fillable array in your model.`protected $fillable = ['slug', 'description','title', 'content', 'image', 'status', 'category_id', 'featured', 'date']`

Comment: Hey Marco. I am the one who answered you in github. It's solved? I wish so.